# Django deployment with Zappa - root URL is wrong

Tags: django, zappa, python-zappa

I have successfully set up a Django app following a Zappa tutorial I found. However, the problem is that Zappa deploys my app to the location:

```
 https://some-aws-address/devel
```

where "devel" is the name of my particular Zappa deployment.

The problem with this is that, at this position, I have pages that have links on them beginning with a '/' that map to:

```
 https://some-aws-address/
```

and *not* (as I would want):

```
https://some-aws-address/devel
```

For example, in one of my template files I have a link on an image:

```
<a href="/"><img src="{% static 'images/main/ryzosens-logo-white-background.png' %}"></a>
```

where the href="/" always maps to https://some-aws-address/

I don't want to have to do some hack to get my root URLS to map to https://some-aws-address/devel, so the question is:

What must I have in my Django settings (or elsewhere) so that my URL root '/' maps to the HTTP endpoint that Zappa creates?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Have a look at the mappings of the routes in API gateway

Comment: I don't believe there are settings in Zappa to get rid of the stage suffix; that's required in AWS API Gateway rest endpoints.  So, I set up a Cloudfront distribution and used a Cloudfront function to solve the same issue for my Zappa deployed Flask app: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69504366/use-cloudfront-to-remove-stage-from-custom-domain-url/69545281#69545281

Answer (score 1):

The URL suffix is an API Gateway convention: it automatically appends the mandatory stage name to the URL.

I don't think there is an API Gateway or Zappa parameters to change it.

It's recommended to use a custom domain and a custom subdomains for each stage. Thus you can choose a user-friendly URL that matches your needs.

You can also update your STATIC_URL to include the stage. One way to do it is to add the stage as an environment variable and write something like this in your settings.py:

```
STATIC_URL = os.environ.get("STAGE") + "/static/"
```

Although I recommend to use a custom domain so you have more control.

Comment: So I had the same issue as the OP and used a mapped my API to a custom domain name via API Gateway.  Is there any way I can achieve the same result via Cloudfront instead of API Gateway?

Comment: You might want to use a custom domain name in Cloudfront the same way you did for API Gateway.

Comment: Thanks, Antoine.  I have a custom domain name in Cloudfront but the issue was that my distribution was pointing to an API Gateway endpoint that contained a URL suffix which was breaking the links to assets stored in subfolders.  I ended up implementing using Cloudfront functions to solve the problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69504366/use-cloudfront-to-remove-stage-from-custom-domain-url/69545281#69545281