# Use Cloudfront to remove {stage} from custom domain url

Tags: amazon-web-services, flask, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cloudfront, domain-mapping

I have a flask app deployed to AWS Lambda via zappa.  Zappa creates an AWS rest endpoint such as `random_api_ID.execute-api.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/dev`which works perfectly when directly entered into the browser.  But, when I use Cloudfront to associate this end point to my custom domain, `dev.mywebsite.com`, I get a 404 error in the response for any assets stored in a subfolder.  The reason is because Cloudfront is serving urls such as

`dev.mywebsite.com/dev/static/css/style.css`

instead of

`dev.mywebsite.com/static/css/style.css`

Also, this works:  `random_api_ID.execute-api.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/dev/static/css/style.css`

But this does not:  `random_api_ID.execute-api.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/static/css/style.css`

So, somehow, I need Cloudfront to associate `random_api_ID.execute-api.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/dev` with `dev.mywebsite.com` instead of `dev.mywebsite.com/dev`.

My Cloudfront distribution has the following parameters:

```
 Alternate Domain Name: dev.mywebsite.com 
 Origin Domain: random_api_ID.execute-api.us-east-2.amazonaws.com
 Origin Path: dev <-- this is the stage name
```

I've tried mapping a custom domain to the zappa-generated AWS rest endpoint via AWS API Gateway; however, that solution produces a private Cloudfront domain that I have no control over; I prefer a solution that involves configuring Cloudfront.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this [article](https://advancedweb.hu/how-to-use-cloudfront-functions-to-change-the-origin-request-path/) and ended up solving the problem by using Cloudfront Functions:

1. Make sure you have a Cloudfront distribution that's **a)** associated with your AWS API Gateway endpoint and **b)** contains your custom domain name.
2. Within the `origin` tab of your distribution, I entered the full AWS
   API Gateway endpoint.  My app uses an endpoint automatically generated by Zappa,`random_api_ID.execute-api.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/dev`.  Entering the full endpoint into the `origin domain` field should
   automatically populate the `origin path` field with `\dev`.
3. In the Cloudfront navigation pane, choose `Functions` then click the `Create function` button.
4. Enter a function nam, then click `Create Function`.
5. With the `Build tab` selected, go to the `Function Code` section and enter the following Javascript:

   ```
   function handler(event) {
       var request = event.request;
       request.uri = request.uri.replace(/^\/[^/]*\//, "/"); 
       return request;
   }
   ```

[image]

6. Save your function
7. Test your function by clicking the `Test` tab and enter a url with an appended stage name:

[image]

8. Clicking the `test function` button. You should get a successful execution message below your function code:

[image]

9. Click the `Publish` tab and publish your function by clicking the `Publish function` button.
10. Under the publish section, you need to associate the published function to your Cloudfront distribution.  Click the `Add distribution` button.
11. In the new window, select a distribution and click the `Add Association` button.

[image]

12. Wait for Cloudfront to finish deploying your distribution.  When it's finished, check your custom domain in the browser and make sure assets are successfully loaded.

Answer (score 0):

There is an option that you are able to add your `stageName` to make your URL to be accessible without it.

Reference: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/distribution-web-values-specify.html#DownloadDistValuesOriginPath

Go to your **CloudFront's Distribution**, edit your `Origin` which points to API Gateway URL.

- Find the `Origin path` option
- Place your `stageName` into it (my example is `dev` stage) so it should be `/dev` (need to have `/` at prefix)

[image: CloudFront Origin Config]

Then click **Save changes** and wait for the deployment around 5 minutes. And try to access it as you would love to

```
https://<domainName>/<resourceName>
```

Comment: My stage name is also called `dev` and when I entered it in the `origin path` field, Cloudfront serves the url with `dev` appended to the root.  When I leave `origin path` blank, them the browser fails to load the url without the stage name.  What might be causing us to get different results?

Comment: Also, I noticed that in your `origin path` field, you entered `dev` instead of `/dev`.  When I enter my stage name in that field without the forward slash and try to save my changes, Cloudfront returns the error, `Failed to create origin: The parameter originPath contains one or more parameters that are not valid.`.  What am I missing?

Comment: When you leave the origin path blank, it just maps between your CloudFront DNS with your API DNS so if you want to access your dev stage, the CloudFront DNS needs to have <cloudfront-dns>/dev. So if we add the origin path, we no need to add that /dev right.

Comment: Your comment `so if you want to access your dev stage, the CloudFront DNS needs to have <cloudfront-dns>/dev. So if we add the origin path, we no need to add that /dev right`, I need to have the cloudfront-dns to include the api-dns with the stage name.  In other words: `cloudfront_dns = api_dns/{stage}`.  But, when adding `stage` in the `origin-path`, it seems that Cloudfront produces `cloudfront_dns/{stage} = api_dns/{stage}`

Comment: Yes, if you use Origin Path, it helps you to add the {stage} hiddenly without typing it into the domain name. Ah wait, after checking my origin path, it should have the / at prefix. Sorry for my confusion ^^

Comment: No worries about the `/` at prefix.  Ok, so I leave `origin path` empty, then the issue is that I need to type `dev.myexample.com\dev` in order for the app to work.  This is not ideal bc when I migrate to production, I can't have my users remember to type `www.myexample.com/prod` every time they want to use my app.  What I need is when a user types www.myexample.com, Cloudfront serves them 'api_dns/prod'.

Comment: So you need to have 2 CloudFront distribution, 1 for dev and 1 for prod. Each distribution, you edit your origin and add the Origin Path :D

Comment: Right, your solution of leaving `origin path` empty and then just typing `devtest.mywebsite.com/dev` will work just fine.  But, then in production, I will have the same issue that I have now; I will need to populate `origin path` with `/dev` and then the `static` assets will return a 404.  This is why I would like to have this problem solved in dev since production should mirror development.

Comment: I don't see your points of using dev resources with Prod stage. You need to have your Prod resources also and it must be under Prod stage.

Comment: My mistake... Regarding my previous comment, I meant to say that in production, I will have the same issue that I have now; I will need to populate origin path with `/prod` and then the static assets will return a 404.

Comment: This solution did not work for me as leaving `origin path` blank will require my users to type `www.mywebsite.com/dev` every time they visit my app.  Thus, I prefer the solution using Cloudfront functions as detailed in the selected answer.  Thanks for trying, Leondkr!